# Solution verification $\left(A \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap B^c\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that: $\left(A \cap B\right) \cup \left(A \cap B^c\right)=A$

Attempt: $$\left[\left(A \cap B\right) \cup A\right] \cup \left[\left(A \cap B\right)\cup B^c\right] \iff \left[A \cup \left(A \cap B \right)\right] \cup A= A$$

I'm right?

Comment: Prove that what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your answer has a mistake

The mistake is in this past

$[(A∩B)∪A]∪[(A∩B)∪B^c]$

The correct one is

$[(A∩B)∪A]∩[(A∩B)∪B^c]$

---

You can solve the equation easily

$(A∩B)∪(A∩B^c)$

$=(A∪(A∩B^c))∩(B∪(A∩B^c))$

$=A∩(B∪A)$

$=A$

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is incorrect. Remember, in general, $\color{blue}X \color{blue}\cup (Y\cap Z)=(\color{blue}X \color{blue}\cup Y)\cap(\color{blue}X \color{blue}\cup Z)$. You wrote

$$\color{blue}{\left(A \cap B\right)} \color{blue}\cup \left(A \cap B^c\right)=\left[\color{blue}{\left(A \cap B\right)} \color{blue}\cup A\right]\color{red}{\cup }\left[\color{blue}{\left(A \cap B\right)} \color{blue}\cup B^c\right],$$

but the red $\cup$ should be a $\cap$.